# Does sklearn support a cost matrix?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is it possible to train classifiers in sklearn with a cost matrix with different costs for different mistakes? For example in a 2 class problem, the cost matrix would be a 2 by 2 square matrix. For example A_ij = cost of classifying i as j.

The main classifier I am using is a Random Forest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The cost-sensitive framework you describe is not supported in scikit-learn, in any of the classifiers we have.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a custom [scoring function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) that accepts a matrix of per-class or per-instance costs.  Here's an example of a scorer that calculates per-instance misclassification cost:

```
def financial_loss_scorer(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    import pandas as pd

    totals = kwargs['totals']

    # Create an indicator - 0 if correct, 1 otherwise
    errors = pd.DataFrame((~(y == y_pred)).astype(int).rename('Result'))
    # Use the product totals dataset to create results
    results = errors.merge(totals, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
    # Calculate per-prediction loss
    loss = results.Result * results.SumNetAmount

    return loss.sum()
```

The scorer becomes:

```
make_scorer(financial_loss_scorer, totals=totals_data, greater_is_better=False)
```

Where `totals_data` is a pandas.DataFrame with indexes that match the training set indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You could always just look at your ROC curve. Each point on the ROC curve corresponds to a separate confusion matrix. So by specifying the confusion matrix you want, via choosing your classifier threshold implies some sort of cost weighting scheme. Then you just have to choose the confusion matrix that would imply the cost matrix you are looking for.

On the other hand if you really had your heart set on it, and really want to "train" an algorithm using a cost matrix, you could "sort of" do it in sklearn.

Although it is impossible to directly train an algorithm to be cost sensitive in sklearn you could use a cost matrix sort of setup to tune your hyper-parameters. I've done something similar to this using a genetic algorithm. It really doesn't do a great job, but it should give a modest boost to performance.

Comment: I think what he means is more in the training step so that the eventual goal would be decreasing the total cost of errors rather than errors that have exact same penalty. ROC will give us the report after the fact and only has one degree of freedom (threshold) for you to modify. But if you train the model based on specific error cost you can use many more degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 3):

One way to circumvent this limitation is to use under or oversampling. E.g., if you are doing binary classification with an imbalanced dataset, and want to make errors on the minority class more costly, you could oversample it. You may want to have a look at [imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) which is a package from scikit-learn-contrib.

Comment: your link really helps!

Answer (score 2):

May not be direct to your question (since you are asking about Random Forest). 
But for SVM (in Sklearn), you can utilize the *class_weight* parameter to specify the weights of different classes. Essentially, you will pass in a dictionary.

You might want to refer to this [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html) to see an example of using *class_weight*.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)